# Counting Distinct Columns Based on Count of third column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, multidimensional-array

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT job_id, cust_id, a.skill_id FROM aaa.jp_job_skill_ref a INNER JOIN aaa.jp_cust_skill_ref b ON a.skill_id = b.skill_id ORDER BY `job_id`, `cust_id`, `skill_id`;
```

Returns 3 columns of data. However, both tables are reference tables with hundreds of the same cust_id and skill_id, or job_id and skill_id, so a count(a.skill_id) with a group by job_id and cust_id returns a skill_id count of 30+

```
 job_id, cust_id, skill_id
     2,       1,        1
     2,       1,        2
     2,       1,        9
     2,       3,        1
     2,       3,        2
     2,       3,        9
     2,       3,       10
     2,       4,        1
     2,       4,        9
     3,       1,       12
     3,       3,       10
     3,       4,       12
```

What I would LIKE it to return is The Job ID, the Cust Id, and the count of different Skill_ID's. What am I missing to return the following dataset:?

```
job_id, cust_id, skill_id
'2',   '1',     '3'
'2',   '3',     '4'
'2',   '4',     '2'
'3',   '1',     '1'
'3',   '3',     '1'
'3',   '4',     '1'
```

Comment: that aren't distinct? then take it out of the query?

Comment: This question is not very good - and presumably you've misunderstood the meaning of/purpose of the DISTINCT operator

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, I edited the question to clarify a little more. I want the job_id, cust_id, and the amount of rows in which job id and cust id are distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `group by`:

```
SELECT job_id, cust_id, count(distinct a.skill_id)
FROM aaa.jp_job_skill_ref a INNER JOIN
     aaa.jp_cust_skill_ref b
     ON a.skill_id = b.skill_id
GROUP BY `job_id`, `cust_id`;
```

This is a very basic SQL query.  `group by` is an important part of the SQL language.  You should probably study up on it so you can use SQL.

Comment: This would work awesome, but the two reference tables I'm pulling on have multiple of the same rows of cust_id and skill_id, or job_id and skill_id. so it turns into a count of 98, instead of a count of 3 like selecting the original distinct query

Comment: do you want `count(distinct a.skill_id)`?

Comment: @flaschenpost . . . Definitely.  On closer reading, the original question is pretty clear that this is what the OP wants.

Comment: count(distinct a.skill_id) returns a single row with the first job, the first customer, and a count of 7 (which I'm pretty sure isn't right)

Comment: @Danejir . . . It results a single row even when you have a `group by` clause?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nope, that worked and apparently I need to go back and learn my database methods

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this ?

```
select 
j1.job_id,
j1.cust_id,
j2.cnt as skill_id
from jp_job_skill_ref j1
inner join (
  select 
  job_id,
  cust_id,
  count(skill_id) as `cnt`
  from jp_job_skill_ref 
  group by job_id,cust_id

)j2
on j1.job_id = j2.job_id AND j1.cust_id = j2.cust_id
group by j1.job_id,j1.cust_id;
```

If you need distinct count of skill_id, just replace

```
count(skill_id) as `cnt`
```

to

```
count(distinct skill_id) as `cnt`
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a582d/8)**

I have replaced the table name `aaa.jp_job_skill_ref` to just `jp_job_skill_ref` in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 2 job_id, 1 cust_id, 3 skill_id
UNION
SELECT 2,3,4
UNION
SELECT 2,4,2
UNION
SELECT 3,1,1
UNION
SELECT 3,3,1
UNION
SELECT 3,4,1;
```

Comment: Is this really answers OP's question ? i don't see the count calculation here

Comment: Yes. This fully satisfies the OP's requirement, as described. Had the OP wanted a better answer, they might have asked a better question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(job_id, cust_id), a.skill_id 
FROM aaa.jp_job_skill_ref a 
INNER JOIN aaa.jp_cust_skill_ref b 
ON a.skill_id = b.skill_id 
ORDER BY `job_id`, `cust_id`, `skill_id`;
```